# Referenciar todas as celulas com uma determinada string

Tags: microsoft-excel

Eu não sei se é possível ou não, mas é possível referenciar todas em células com uma determinada String numa só célula?

Por exemplo, eu neste momento queria que a célula da coluna F fosse todos os valores da coluna B que tenham na String `q*w*`. Não precisa de ter uma lista visivel de todas as Strings de B, mas precisava que "apanhasse" todas elas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual seria o resultado esperado? Em uma única célula aparecer B65, B67, etc...?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o que você queira possa ser obtido com `&`

```
Celula A1-> Hello
Celula A2-> World
Celula A3-> !!!
Celula A4-> =A1&" "&A2&A3
```